# logger driver in android lollipop kernel

Tags: logging, driver, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-kernel

In android 4.4.2, logger driver (drivers/staging/android/logger.c) was used to read and write android logs to /dev/log/(main or system). In android lollipop, Logger driver logger.c is removed. Then how does logcat reads android logs? where is reading and writing of android logs handled at kernel?

Answer (score 4):

Android provides two options now. If the board is defined to use the logger driver (TARGET_USES_LOGD:=false) it does so, otherwise it uses a service called logd (check your init.rc) which publishes a UNIX socket, that provides pretty much the same interface as the driver did. This means that the default option now is to *not* use the kernel driver.

If you're curious, this is the commit that brought logd to life: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/154f4608aac6218af0e25c98b71d0803278c047e